# Incomplete data from InputStream of URLConnection

Tags: java, inputstream

Here is my simple test code to show the problem:

```
URL u = new URL(someURLString);
URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

int amount = c.getContentLength(); //gives 75830, which is correct

int r = 0;
while (is.read() != -1) //count input
    r++;

//r is 65878, what the hell?
```

Obviously there is data missing. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: this is just test code to show the problem, but in the end a want to go through the page line by line to extract some information

Answer (score 2):

The Question is 6 Months old now, so I dont know if you have solved your Problem in the meantime. But...

I had the same Problem with running a HttpUrlConnection on an Android Application. 
The Content was **incomplete** on the **logcat**! I wrote the content into a File on my Device and it showed me the whole Content.
Maybe this seems to be an Issue with logcat, but it took me hours!

Answer (score -1):

`c.getContentLength();`-   Returns the value of the content-length header field.
Just check what content you are receiving is correct or not

Comment: i see, but i already checked: the data is definitely incomplete

Comment: is this code even correct ? how does `int c;` compile when you have `URLConnection c = u.openConnection();`